# Extract one dimension signal from <Signal2D, title: , dimensions: (10|4096, 4096)>

Tags: python, signals

I am plotting TEM images with the format of `.emi` or `.ser`.

The package I am using is HyperSpy.

After I load the data, the data type is `<Signal2D, title: , dimensions: (10|4096, 4096)>`. Therefore, when I plot, I will get an image with 10 subplot. But only the first one is useful. May I ask if there's anypossiblity I can plot only the first image? Kind of extract one dimension from the signal.

Comment: Are you sure that the code or a function in a title is a good idea?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The can use the `inav` syntax of hyperspy to slice only the first index of the navigation dimension:

```
s2 = s.inav[0]
```

Example:

```
import hyperspy.api as hs
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random_sample((10, 100, 100))
s = hs.signals.Signal2D(data)
s
```

s has navigation dimension of 10 and signal dimension of (100, 100)

```
<Signal2D, title: , dimensions: (10|100, 100)>
```

Use `inav` to slice only the first index

```
s2 = s.inav[0]
s2
```

s2 has navigation dimension of 0 and signal dimension of (100, 100)

```
<Signal2D, title: , dimensions: (|100, 100)>
```

If you want to know more about the indexing/slicing syntax in hyperspy, see https://hyperspy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/signal.html#indexing